# How can I secure log-in without SSL?

Tags: asp.net, security

My web hosting service does not give me SSL. I'm wondering if there is a way to secure log-in with out it. Its not a high risk web application, but there is a log-in to edit content and I don't want the site hacked.

Comment: I'd find a hosting provider that *does* give you SSL.  Secure hosting is cheap, and without transport-level encryption (SSL), you are open to man-in-the-middle attacks, among other things.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions.  I haven't gone live just yet.  My application is using ASP.Net with 4.0 of the framework.  No MVC just pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: No.**

Without SSL, you will have a fundamentally insecure log-in.